# How to update a label's text in a screen - Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I've been trying to make a program that continuously updates and displays the readings obtained from a sensor. However, after the sensor value is updated, the label still displays the old values in the background. How do i clear the screen before the new values are displayed?

I've tried the `self.clear_screen` but that didn't help. What am i missing?

**.py file:**

```
class MainScreen(Screen):
   pass



class ScreenThermo(Screen):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(ScreenThermo, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.getTemp, 2)


    def getTemp(self,dt):
        temperature = sensor.get_temperature()
        thetemp = temperature 
        self.manager.screen_thermo.ids.TempLabel.text = str(thetemp)


    def on_enter(self, *args):
        self.__init__()

    pass

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
   pass
```

**.kv file**

```
ScreenManagement:    
    id: screen_manager
    screen_thermo: screen_thermo
    MainScreen:
    ScreenThermo:
        id: screen_thermo
        name: 'thermo'
        manager: screen_manager

<MainScreen>:
    name: "main"
    Label:
        text: "Welcome to \n Interactive HealthCare \n System"
        font_size: 60
        halign: 'center'
        valign: 'middle'
        pos_hint: {'x': .01, 'y': .05}
        on_touch_down: app.root.current = "thermo"



<ScreenThermo>:
    Label:
        text: "temperature"
        font_size: 60
        text_size: root.width, None
        size: self.texture_size
        halign: 'left'
        valign: 'middle'
    Label:
        id: TempLabel
        text: "temperature updated"
        font_size: 60
        text_size: root.width, None
        size: self.texture_size
        halign: 'center'
        valign: 'middle'
```

Answer (score 0):

## ScreenThermo - Labels Overwritten

`ScreenThermo` is displaying 2 Labels but they are overwritten or super-imposed i.e. one is in the background and the other is in the foreground.

### Soltion

Add a `BoxLayout` to separate the two `Labels`.

#### Snippets - kv

```
<ScreenThermo>:
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            text: "temperature"
            font_size: 60
            text_size: self.size
            halign: 'left'
            valign: 'middle'
        Label:
            id: TempLabel
            text: "temperature updated"
            font_size: 60
            text_size: self.size
            halign: 'center'
            valign: 'middle'
```

## Root Cause - label still displays the old values

The old values are being displayed because the following create a Label that can grow vertically but wraps the text at a certain width.

```
Label:
    text_size: root.width, None
    size: self.texture_size
```

## Solution

- Remove `text_size: root.width, None` and `size: self.texture_size`.
- Add `text_size: self.size`.

### Example

The following code binds this size to the size of the Label, so text will be aligned within the widget bounds. This will also automatically wrap the text of the Label to remain within this area.

```
Label:
    text_size: self.size
    halign: 'right'
    valign: 'middle'
```

Comment: I've tried adding ` text_size: self.size ` but the problem still remains. It's still displaying the previous values in the background and overwriting on them.

Comment: Could you please post a print screen.

Comment: The two `Labels` are being overwritten/super-imposed because it is missing a layout. Add a `BoxLayout` to separate them. Please refer to updated post for details.

Comment: Okay, I've increased the value of dt and it's working now.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please remember to accept and/or up-vote the answer.

Comment: I'm new to the community. So, I won't be able to upvote until I've 15 reputation :/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)
*If you want to say "thank you," vote on or accept that person's answer.*